# Cardano Transaction Submit Errors

Tags: transaction, cardano-serialization-lib

I am currently building a dApp on cardano using `cardano-serialization-lib` and wallets (Nami, Typhon, Yoroi).

Since you have to configure `TransactionBuilder` with the latest Protocol Parameters, there is a chance that a transaction will fail due to wrong parameters being used while building the transaction (ex. `FeeTooSmallUTXO` if `min_fee_a` or `min_fee_b` was raised).

At the same time, not every error, thrown at transaction submit is related to these parameters (ex. `NonOutputSupplementaryDatums`).

Is there a page or a document that lists errors that can be caused by the protocol parameters mismatch or all errors, but with explanation for when they occur? I want to look through such list to figure out all the scenarios where I might want to check for a parameter update.

Answer (score 0):

The Cardano ledger itself provides the list of [UtxoPredicateFailure](https://input-output-hk.github.io/ouroboros-network/cardano-ledger-shelley-ma/Cardano-Ledger-ShelleyMA-Rules-Utxo.html).